# How to cast a time interval into a decimal value in postgresql?

Tags: sql, date, casting, amazon-redshift

When running this query:

```
SELECT
  start_date,
  end_date,
  end_date-start_date as timediff

FROM content_events
```

I get a table like this:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------+
| start_date          | end_date            | timediff        |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------+
| 2017-03-23 23:00:00 | 2017-04-01 22:00:00 | 8 days 23:00:00 |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------+
```

But I'd like to get something like this:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------+
| start_date          | end_date            | timediff        |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------+
| 2017-03-23 23:00:00 | 2017-04-01 22:00:00 | 8,96            |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------+
```

Note that I just need to get the time difference as a numeric value with two decimals.

I am using PostgreSQL 8.0.2.

Many thanks!

Comment: `SELECT ..., extract(epoch from end_date-start_date)/(24*60*60) as timediff FROM content_events;` [Doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT)

Comment: are you sure about the version?..

Comment: @VaoTsun Yep, this is what I get: version
PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.1232

Comment: ah, redshift...

Comment: hi @Abelisto just realised that the calculation does not work properly for certain dates https://screencast.com/t/Kjg9eord5Lco As you can see in that screenshot, when using _start_date_: '02/04/17 22:00' and _end_date_: '20/05/17 22:00', the difference is not correct. It returns 78 days. **Note:** The column _Days Left_ is the difference between _end_date_ & _current_date_

Comment: @Henry And what the result of `select extract(epoch from '2017-05-20 22:00:00'::timestamp - '2017-04-02 22:00:00'::timestamp)/(24*60*60);`?

Comment: @Abelisto it works that way, but when I use the column names (see at the end of this message) instead of hardcoded values I get the wrong result again (78 days): extract(epoch from end_date::timestamp - start_date::timestamp)/(24*60*60) as total_dayss,

Comment: Hi @Abelisto Let me know if you have found the answer to this please. Thanks sor far for your help!

Comment: Unfortunately **I** can not debug **your** database. Start from the simplest  case: `create table foo(ds timestamp, de timestamp); insert into foo values('2017-04-02 22:00:00', '2017-05-20 22:00:00'); select de - ds from foo;` etc.

Comment: thanks @Abelisto for your reply. So I just tried these two select statements: **1)**  extract(epoch from end_date::timestamp - start_date::timestamp)/(24*60*60) as total_days_A and **2)** end_date - start_date as total_days_B .The second one actually gets the correct result: https://screencast.com/t/ZGohBESU Now the question is how I can edit the correct statement so the result doesn't display 'days' & shows two decimals. Thanks again!

Comment: Apologies for chasing @Abelisto, I just feel we are very close to having this done. Let me know please what other info you need & will surely send it your way. Many thanks!

Comment: It is RedShift and PostgreSQL 8.0.2. I have no access to them. I feeling that it is problem with intervals more then one month. Make more test cases with various dates and intervals and create another question, why it is not working as expecting. PS Do not use screen shots. PPS Good luck.

Comment: Ok, will do. Thank you @Abelisto for your time :)

Comment: @Abelisto got the answer, below. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This `select` statement works fine:

```
(date_part(epoch,end_date)::float - date_part(epoch,start_date)::float)/(24*60*60) as timediff
```

or this one too:

```
(extract(epoch from end_date)::float - extract(epoch from start_date)::float)/(24*60*60) as timediff
```